# How to figure out second parameter/register in reverse engineering assembly?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

so Im doing a variation of the binary bomb. Heres what the phase is

```
0x0000000000401205 <+0>:     sub    $0x8,%rsp
0x0000000000401209 <+4>:     cmp    $0x3,%rdi                    #rdi = 3
0x000000000040120d <+8>:     je     0x40121d <phase_2+24>        #if(rdi == 3) skip explosion 
0x000000000040120f <+10>:    callq  0x401c01 <bomb_ignition>
0x0000000000401214 <+15>:    mov    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
0x000000000040121b <+22>:    jmp    0x40124c <phase_2+71>
0x000000000040121d <+24>:    xor    $0xffffffffffffff1c,%rsi     #rsi ^= 0xffffffffffffff1c
0x0000000000401224 <+31>:    and    %rsi,%rdx                    #rdx &= rsi
0x0000000000401227 <+34>:    add    $0x1c8,%rdx                  #rdx += 456 
0x000000000040122e <+41>:    cmp    $0x2c5,%rdx                  #rdx == 709
0x0000000000401235 <+48>:    sete   %al 
0x0000000000401238 <+51>:    movzbl %al,%eax
0x000000000040123b <+54>:    cmp    %rcx,%rdx                    #rdx == rcx
0x000000000040123e <+57>:    je     0x40124c <phase_2+71>
0x0000000000401240 <+59>:    callq  0x401c01 <bomb_ignition>
0x0000000000401245 <+64>:    mov    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
0x000000000040124c <+71>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
0x0000000000401250 <+75>:    retq
```

Ive annotated what i think it means next to the asm. What Im stuck on is `<+24>` where it `xors` `$0xffffffffffffff1c` and `%rsi`. `%rsi` is the second parameter passed correct? So how do I figure out what it is so i can `xor` it? Because it then `and`s it to `%rdx` which is the third parameter.

So what I think it does it take 4 numbers. 1st is '3' (right?). Then `xor` the second with 0xffffffffffffff1c. `And`s this to the third number. Then third number adds 456, and should be 709. Which is what the 4th number should be. Also Im still a bit confused on `sete` and `movzbl`. But I cant figure out what the second and third number should be. Am I correct in my prediction? ANY HELP APPRECIATED. Thanks

Comment: sete / movzbl get the preceding compare result as a 0/1 integer in `%eax`.  e.g. they implement this C: `bool eax = (rdx == 0x2c5)`.  Looks like that has nothing to do with the bomb, though.  It's just a return value, so I guess it's a red herring.

Comment: BTW, this is one of the only well-asked binary-bomb help questions I've ever seen on SO.  You did a great job explaining what you understand, and asking a fairly specific question about the exact place you're stuck.  Many binary-bomb questions don't have any of that, just a code-dump.

Comment: If rsi = 0xe1, rdx = 0xff, and rcx = 0x2c5, then rax is set to 1 and bomb_ignition is not called. There are many other combinations of values that can lead to this result, and other combinations of values that result in rax = 0 but no call to bomb_ignition.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. for the `sete/movzbl` explanation and for saying i asked a question nicely.

Comment: @prl Hmm. I tried inputting `3 225 255 709`, but it still blew up. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: @prl wait. I just tried `225 255 709` and it worked! THANK YOU. I think `cmp    $0x3,%rdi` is comparing number of inputs. Would you mind explaining how exactly you figured out that if `rsi = 0xe1, rdx = 0xff, and rcx = 0x2c5` then the bomb will not go off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the caller check the return value?  I'm assuming so, otherwise you could choose whatever you want for rsi and rdx, and then calculate what rcx will match.  It sets `rax` = -1 (bomb explosion), or 0 or 1 (`sete/movzx`) based on the `cmp $0x2c5,%rdx` result.

Lets name our function inputs so we can talk about the function args separately from the current value in a register: x:`rsi`, y:`rdx`, and z:`rcx`.  (Ignoring the first arg in `rdi`, which is checked separately).

`z` only interacts with the others once, so it can be chosen freely.

```
rsi ^= -228;  // 0xffffffffffffff1c
rdx &= rsi;   // rdx &= (x ^ -228)
rdx += 456

if(rdx != rcx) explode();
```

We're assuming we also need rdx == 709 = 0x2c5 (and thus `z` = 709, too).  Let's work backwards from `rdx == 709`:

```
709 - 456 = 253   // rdx before  add    $0x1c8,%rdx
```

**Then we need `x` and `y` such that `y & (x^-228) == 253`**.  This is one equation in 2 variables, so there should be multiple solutions.  The "simplest" would be `y` = 253 (0xfd), and then choose an `x` that will leave all of those bits set.

For example, choose `x` so that `x ^ 0x1c == 0xfd` as well.  (We can ignore the high bits, because AND with 0xfd clears them).  You can solve this equation like you would for addition.  `xor` is its own inverse (and is commutative/associative), so we can `xor` both sides by `0x1c` to solve for `x = 0xfd ^ 0x1c = 0xe1 = 225`.

@Prl's solution uses `x = 0xe1` but `y=255`.  This is fine; extra set bits are wiped away by the AND.

Comment: Thanks. I actually got to `y & (x^-228) = 253` but stopped there thinking I was wrong because I was in the math mindset, and thought it was unsolvable because of 2 unknowns. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe: Technically, from a math standpoint, it's solveable but doesn't have a *unique* solution.  You'd only have a math problem if you had too *few* free parameters, not too many.  But yeah, I know what you mean, that you were expecting there to be a unique solution.  Too bad you didn't post `y & (x^-228) = 253` in the question as part of what you'd figured out, or at least thought you'd figured out.